# uploading multiple text files using flask in python3

Tags: python, flask

I am making a `webtool` in which I would like to upload some text files, to do so I am using flask as follows: (I have 2 scrips: 1- `flask.py` and the 2nd script is: `upload.html`)

flask.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return 'file uploaded successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

and the 2nd script which is in the templates folder, is:

upload.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

when I run it, I would get this error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: upload_file
```

do you know how to fix it?